# Problem using Almanah

Tags: software-installation

I have used the diary program Almanah previously and know how it looks and works normally. Recently I installed a fresh Ubuntu 20.04.1 and installed Almanah but it lacks "Settings" or I do not see the "Gear button." If I open Almanah on a terminal, I get these warnings:

```
(almanah:4417): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:17:35.459: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:31: not a number
(almanah:4417): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:17:35.460: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:38: Using Pango syntax for the font: style property is deprecated; please use CSS syntax
```

Comment: Those warnings are for the developer of the app. Please inform them (-> https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/almanah ) by filing bug reports if those do not exist yet. Besides that... " but it lacks "Settings" or I do not see the "Gear botton." I would switch themes and see if that fixes it. The 1st warning is a theming error that might be the reason. The 2nd is a warning about future removal of a used method. So not interesting.

Comment: I have changed themes a couple of times now  but it does not help.

Comment: I have been in contact with App developers. They confirm that the same version of Almanah functions and looks right in other distributions- they sent även a screen shut. Their conclusion is that there must be a problem with Ubuntus packaging or how window decorations are set up. I have tried även Mate version. Unfortunately same problem there.